# Creating anonymous types!

Tags: c#-3.0, anonymous-types

I know that I can do something like this:

```
var test = new { FirstName = string.Empty, LastName = string.empty };
```

But I don't if there's is a way to do it dynamically, let's say:

```
var test = new {};
if (condition) {
    test.Property = string.Empty;
}
```

Let's say I Have this:

```
string[] names = 
{
    "eder",
    "quiñones",
    "quoe840629",
    "3301"
};

var anonymous = new {};
foreach (string name in names) {
    // Create anonymous types...
}
```

Any suggestions?

~ Eder Quiñones

Answer (score 7):

You can do:

```
var test = new { FirstName = (condition ? string.Emtpy : "other") };
```

If you were using c# 4 you could use a `dynamic` type ([`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx)).

Comment: Let's say that I have to create depending on the size of a list of objects more than conditionally!

Comment: N number of properties depending on the size of my list.

Comment: how dynamic is your list.. can it be anything or there are predefined set of properties that the list can have?